# Storing a questionnaire in a Warehouse

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014, data-warehouse

I am currently implementing a data warehouse with SQL Server 2014 and I am struggling with the layout of the dimension tables, well, more the extraction of the data. I have an Excel-File with the following format:

```
+--------+---------+------------+------------+------------+---+-------------+
| Region | Country |  Location  | Question 1 | Question 2 | … | Question 97 |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+------------+---+-------------+
| Africa | Algeria | Location 1 | Yes        | Yes        | … | No          |
| Africa | Algeria | Location 2 | No         | Yes        | … | Yes         |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+------------+---+-------------+
```

There are some more attributes about who answered the question when. As indicated with the dots, there are more than 3 Questions, actually there are 97 of them.
Currently I've imported the excel file into my raw table which represents my preparation area(It has the exact same format as the excel file with first row as headers). Now, when I want to put the data into staging I'm struggling a bit with the layout. So I thought about the layout and since my boss told me that the questions could change in future, I came up with the following two tables:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| DIM_Questionnaire                |
+------------+---------------------+
| PK         | SUR_QuestionnaireID |
| FK         | LocationID          |
| FK         | TimeKey             |
+------------+---------------------+

+--------------+-----------------+
| DIM_Question                   |
+--------------+-----------------+
| PK           | SUR_QuestionID  |
| FK           | QuestionnaireID |
|              | Question        |
|              | Answer          |
|              | Category        |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

The Survey is then added to a fact table.  What do you think about this solution in a warehouse? Furthermore, how would i be able to get the column name from the raw-table as a value in in the Question table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have worked out a good solution. As you have mentioned, the very first layout is not quite good since many times the number of questions per survey may change and if you have 97 question columns for example, if you get a requirement to hold 100 questions, you have to change the table structure. and if the questions are about 20, you waste lot of columns unnecessarily. Good work on figuring out the structure.

Your structure looks fine to me. Just one thing I want to clarify from you?  the answer in the DIM_Question table is the correct answer right? The answers that users provide should go to another answer table which holds the DIM_Question SK so that any time you can link the answer with the exact question on the question dimension.

And one more thing, why did you add the survey table as a fact table? i think your measures are "answers" right? for example, if someone asks "How many of them answered correctly to this question?", "what type of answers that people have provided for this question?" etc etc. I think you should double check on that. If you are stuck, just provide some hits on the actual requirement, so we can figure it out.

and finally for your next question "how would i be able to get the column name from the raw-table as a value in in the Question table? " I think you can get the table column names from below query

```
SELECT *
FROM <database_name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Dim_Table'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! No the answer in the question table is the answer given from the user. I could load the answers into another table but then I'd need another join. I didn't mean to make the Survey table a fact table, just that it is linked to fact table since there is more than just the questionnaire.

Comment: If the (many different) answers given by respondents are in the questions table, then it shouldn't be a dimension table.  Or, at least, it shouldn't be called DIM_Questions, but DIM_QuestionAnswers.  This would only make sense if possible answers are highly constrained (e.g. "Yes" "No" etc multi-select values).

Comment: I think the best approach would be to have the answers in another table rather than including it in question table. Though it is another table join, still it is worth enough to do it since say, if one question has many answers given by the users, you will have to repeat all question related fields in the table just to store a different answer for the same question which is a bad approach and a design to have. and analytics would be difficult and you will be using unnecessary storage. What do you think

Answer (score 0):

If your target is transform your columns in rows using SSIS there is the "Unpivot" task that could be useful.

See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193842/Working-with-Pivot-and-UnPivot-Transformation) will describe in simple ways as how to work with Pivot and Unpivot transformation component.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your terminology means.  It seems that there are multiple Surveys (collections of returned questionnaires, each of which has the same set of question).  But then, surely your Survey dimension should have a FK to a QuestionnaireID?

The structure of your Dim Question isn't consistent with this.  According to the FK to QuestionnaireID, the Questionnaire seems to be the "class" (set of questions sent out to multiple people).  So what's the "instance of the class" (specific copy of the set of questions, returned by one person with answers)?

I think your fact should be **Answer**, with dimensions Question, (possibly) Survey, Questionnaire (could be an attribute of dimension Question).  But I can't be entirely sure about this (except that Answer is definitely the fact) because I'm not sure how you're using the terms.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusing terminology i switched from questionnaire to survey and back again, i've updated the former survey table to the questionnaire table, which it actually is...

Comment: I still don't quite understand.  I think it would be useful to start by describing your fact table and then go from there.